# How does one calculate the number of multiples in a set or list using Python?

Tags: python

I have been generating random sets and lists and was curious about how one would calculate the number of multiples in that given set or list. The code I have written gives me the wrong number, so I am assuming I have allocated something incorrectly. The code is

```
b= random.sample(range(1, 56), 6)
print(b)
numbers = (b)
count_multiples = 0
for y in (b):
    for x in (b):
        if y % x ==0:
            count_multiples+=1
print("MPS:", count_multiples)
```

I am brand new to coding and this exchange, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that I don't understand the _notion_ of _multiples_ (at least in your context). Could some examples be shared - e.g. for `[48, 3, 31, 13, 35, 49]`? Does it have anything to do with _divisors_?

Comment: Do you meant he count of unique values? If so, you can hash your values in a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and find the length: `len(set(b))`

Comment: For this example I am looking at elements in the set that divide other elements in the set, for instance given the set or list (2, 5, 6, 8) there would be two multiples since 2 divides 6 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what exactly you mean by number of multiples in the list.

1). Do you want to count every number at least once, since every number is a multiple of itself?

2). Do you want to count an element more than once if it is a multiple of more than one element in the list?

If you answer yes to both of these questions your code looks fine (although not the most efficient).  If no try something like the following:

```
min, max = 1, 56
n = 6
count = 0 
random_list_with_no_duplicates = random.sample(range(min, max), n)

# If no to 1) but yes to 2)
random_list_with_no_duplicates.sort()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if random_list_with_no_duplicates[j] % random_list_with_no_duplicates[i] == 0:
            count += 1

# If no both
random_list_with_no_duplicates.sort(reverse=True)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):  # change to just 'i' if yes to 1), no to 2)
        if random_list_with_no_duplicates[i] % random_list_with_no_duplicates[j] == 0:
            count += 1
            break
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for the comments! Code is working great.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `True` and `False` are equal to `1` and `0`, respectively. You can take advantage of this and use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to add the booleans together. The result will be the number of elements, `e`, where `bool(e)` evaluates as `True`.

```
count_multiples = sum(y % x == 0 for y in b for x in b)
```